# Request.Url.PathAndQuery in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I moved from Asp.Net Framework to Asp.Net Core. What would be the replacement or equivalent property for `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` in Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to access url path and query string separately using `HttpContext`.

In controller:

```
var path = HttpContext.Request.Path;
var query = HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
var pathAndQuery = path + query;
```

To get `HttpContext`, refer to [How to Access HttpContext in Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 20):

From ASP.NET Core 2.0 onwards [use the `UriHelper.GetEncodedPathAndQuery(HttpRequest)` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getencodedpathandquery).

It's in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` namespace.

For example, inside a `Controller` action method:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

[...]

[Route("/foobar")]
public IActionResult MyControllerAction()
{
    string pathAndQuery = this.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery();
}
```

Comment: This is the actual current answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one also it's work form me.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;    
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;   
/// <summary>
/// Gets the raw target of an HTTP request.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Raw target of an HTTP request</returns>    
/// <remarks>   
/// ASP.NET Core manipulates the HTTP request parameters exposed to pipeline    
/// components via the HttpRequest class. This extension method delivers an untainted   
/// request target. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.3 
/// </remarks>  
public static string GetRawTarget(this HttpRequest request) 
{       
    var httpRequestFeature = request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();       
    return httpRequestFeature.RawTarget;    
}
```

i am creting extension method or Request object.